# Python picture grid in loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I encountered a problem as I tried to fill a tkinter grid with a loop

```
i=0
for category in categories:
    self.image = PhotoImage(file=category[2]+".png")
    imageLabel = Label(master, image=self.image)
    imageLabel.grid(row=0, column=i)
    i = i + 1
```

With this code I try to create a row with different pictures side by side.
But it shows only the last image which is in the categories array (this array was filled by a SQL-execute btw).

After a few researches I found out, that it seems that python overwrites the reference of the picture on each iteration.

So I tried to change the code and save the references in a array:

```
folderPictures = []
i = 0
for category in categories:
    self.image = PhotoImage(file=category[2]+".png")
    imageLabel = Label(master, image=self.image)
    folderPictures.append(imageLabel)

for pictures in folderPictures:
        pictures.grid(row=0, column=i)
        i = +1
```

unfortunately this doesn't work either. What do I do wrong?

Thanks and best regards
Franz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overwriting self.image each time, keep a separate reference for each image. For instance, you could make self.image into an array (self.images[0,1,...]) and keep each image in a different slot.

Answer (score 1):

Load images first and make a list of them, then put in label.

```
images=[] 
for category in categories:
    images.append(PhotoImage(file=category[2]+".png"))
for index,img in enumerate(images):
    Label(master,image=img).grid(row=0,column=index)
```

Answer (score -1):

I saved the reference of the label instead of the ref of the picture.

```
self.image = []
for category in categories:
    self.image.append(PhotoImage(file=category[2]+".png"))
    imageLabel = Label(master, image=self.image[i])
    imageLabel.grid(row=0, column=i)
    i = i + 1
```

this works now!